# Append string to NSXmlParser string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsxmlparser, nsmutablestring

I am using NSXmlParser to extract a string from an XML file. The xml elements look like the following: `<temp_f data="63"/>`

I can successfully log the data from the xml tags but when I try to append a string to that data I receive an error saying: `Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:` The `tempF` is actually a mutable object, it's declared as an `NSMutableString *tempF;` in the header file. I have successfully appended strings to NSMutableSrings before but for some reason it is not working in this case. What am I doing wrong, please help?

My code is:

```
if ([elementName isEqual:@"temp_f"]) {
        tempF = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        tempF = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"];
        [tempF appendString:@"°F"];
        NSLog(@"tempF: %@", tempF);
    }
```

Everything works fine without the `appendString:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with

```
tempF = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

you create a new mutable string and assign a pointer to the new object to the variable `tempF`, but with

```
tempF = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"];
```

directly below, you replace the pointer to the new mutable with a pointer to the string allocated by the XML parser to represent the attribute value -- which is immutable as it seems. (Note, that you also introduce a memory leak). Try instead:

```
tempF = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[tempF appendString: [attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
```

Comment: Aaaaaaahhhhhhhh! Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. I was going nuts trying to figure that out.